# Django REST Framework: Validate before a delete

Tags: django, validation, django-rest-framework

I want to run a validation before an object is deleted, to prevent deletion in certain cases and return as a validation error. How do I do that? What I have currently doesn't seem right:

```
class CallDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    queryset = XCall.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CallSerializer
    ...

    def pre_delete(self, obj):
        if obj.survey:
            raise serializers.ValidationError("Too late to delete")
```

Comment: At first glance this looks right. What's (not) happening when you try this? — What do you see if you drop a breakpoint in pre_delete?

Comment: @CarltonGibson The error doesn't get raised as a DRF error (text response in JSON), but rather as a django/Python error (yellow screen with stack trace if I run from my browser). The issue is that ValidationError is meant to be raised in `validate_...` methods, doing out here in the view makes it like any old python error. Hope that's clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than raising a `ValidationError`, I will just raise a [ParseError](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/exceptions#parseerror) or another custom error that fits the error description:

```
from rest_framework import exceptions
def pre_delete(self, obj):
        if obj.survey:
            raise exceptions.ParseError("Too late to delete")
```

Comment: Where do you define the pre_delete? In the view?

Answer (score 9):

The solution I found was to override the destroy method on the api.

```
class CallDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    queryset = XCall.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CallSerializer
    ...

    def destroy(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        obj = self.get_object()
        if obj.survey:
            return Response(data={'message': "Too late to delete"},
                            status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
        self.perform_destroy(obj)
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
```

For me makes much more sense to validate on the **destroy** method instead of validating on the object permission check as avances123 mentioned, since permission should only check for permission stuffs, and doesn't return any messages related to validation.

Hope that helps ;)

Answer (score 7):

You can solve it with permissions:

```
from rest_framework import permissions

class IsSurvey(permissions.BasePermission):


    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):

        if request.method == 'DELETE' and obj.survey:
            return False


        return True
```

Then add to your view's permission_classes

```
from permissions import IsSurvey

class MyViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    permission_classes = (IsSurvey, )
```

Answer (score 6):

For anyone landing here since V3 like me... :)
You may now use `perform_destroy`:

```
def perform_destroy(self, instance):
    if not can_delete(instance):
        raise ValidationError("You are not allowed to perform this action.")
    instance.delete()
```

Answer (score 0):

### Update

> validate doesn't get called on delete.

Hmmm. Right yes. In that case I'd raise the exception in `pre_delete` just as you are and override `delete` to wrap the `destroy` call in a `try` block.

If you `except ValidationError as e` you can use that to construct the response you want by hand...

```
return Response({"error" : e.message})
```

... or such.

You could probably populate `self._errors` and leverage the existing error response behaviour but I can't think how to do that off-hand.

I hope that helps.

#### First Answer (didn't work):

Check the doc on [Object Level Validation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers.html#object-level-validation).

Implement `validate` to check if the survey is set:

```
def validate(self, attrs):
    if attrs['survey']
        raise serializers.ValidationError("Too late to delete")
    return attrs
```

If `attrs` isn't what you need here you'll have to do something cleverer — but it will get your error in at the validation stage.

I hope that helps.

Comment: Does `validate` get triggered on delete? How do I know the operation is delete?

Comment: I just verified that `validate` doesn't get called on delete. If it could, I could check for delete with `self.context['request'].method`