# Can I disable delete() in django-rest-famework by not calling object.delete()

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a pattern that I use:

```
class View(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):

...

def delete(self, request, pk):
    if cantDelete():
       return JsonResponse({ 'success' : False, 'message': "Can't delete this"})
    self.get_object().delete()
    return JsonResponse({ 'success' : True, 'message': "Deleted"})
```

I have a reason to believe that the objects are sometimes being deleted if cantDelete() is true.  Is this a bad pattern? Can't I disable delete() in this way?

I will do some experiments, but it's a production back end and a bit of an emergency, so if anyone can chime in with an answer before I get a chance to post an answer myself, it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```
def perform_destroy(self, conversation):
    if conversation.messages.exists():
        return Response({'status': 'conversation has messages'}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
    else:
        conversation.delete()
```

But to your question, I would say that if objects are being deleted when cantDelete() is True then they are not being deleted by that delete function.

Comment: Thanks for the info and feedback.  I cannot think how else the object is getting deleted, maybe through foreign keys or something.  It's a big mystery.

Comment: A cascade in the model could certainly delete your objects unbeknownst to DRF.

Comment: Won't suggest sending a 400 status code when the request was clearly understood by the server.

Comment: @jackotonye umm what's wrong with 400? In my example the client is trying to delete something which doesn't exist - that's a client error and hence a 4XX.

Comment: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#section-10.4.1 400 is used for malformed syntax that the server couldn't understand i.e invalid POST data.

Comment: Pedantic and without value in this context. :) I only responded because I thought you were meaning to say it should be a 5XX. Have a good day.

Comment: This code is also wrong since self.get_object() will fail if the object doesn't exists hence calling object.related_objects.exists() will not even be reached since the view will already raise a 404.

Comment: Not in my case, the conversation objects exists - the question is whether it has any messages in it... :)

Answer (score 1):

According to this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/37308092/2073793
a better pattern would be:

```
class View(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):

   ...

   def destroy(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
       if cantDelete():
          return JsonResponse({ 'success' : False, 'message': "Can't delete this"}, status = 403)
       self.perform_destroy(self.get_object())
       return JsonResponse({ 'success' : True, 'message': "Deleted"})
```

That is, override the destroy method (not the delete method), and then call perform_destroy() rather than the object's delete() method to actually delete the object if it's allowed.

But I still don't know whether the original code is problematic or not.

Answer (score 0):

You could call `.perform_destroy` if the `can_delete` is `True`

```
class ConditionalDestroyMixin(object):

    def destroy(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        instance = self.get_object()
        can_delete = instance.can_delete()
        if can_delete:
            self.perform_destroy(instance)
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)

        msg = _(f'Unable to delete {instance}.')
        data = {'detail': six.text_type(msg)}
        return Response(data, status=status.HTTP_403_FORBIDDEN)
```